# Hyper-v guest loses internet if host hibernates

Tags: hyper-v, windows-8.1

I have a laptop running Windows 8.1. This hosts a hyper-v guest running Windows Server 2012 x64 Standard. From the host I, go to Control Panel\Network and Internet\ Network Connections. I right-click my ethernet connection, right-click and select properties. I click the Sharing tab and enable connection sharing. I then start my guest VM and connect to it using remote desktop. At this point all is good, the guest has internet access. However the problem comes, if I close the lid on my laptop to put it into hibernation. When I wake the laptop by opening the lid, the remote desktop session continues to run and I can work on the guest but it has lost its internet connection. The only way I can seem to get it back is to reboot then guest - then all is good again.

Does any know if it's possible to avoid the need for a reboot of the guest following a hibernate on the host?

Thanks,

Rob.

Answer (score 0):

Pause the guest before hibernating the host.

Edit: Also, If you really must use a laptop, then you might be better off running a level 2 hypervisor on top of windows like VMware workstation or VirtualBox etc.

Comment: Why would you recommend VirtualBox over the Hyper-V **built in** to Windows 8.1?

Comment: @MDMarra Simply because Hyper-V is a type one hypervisor - meaning it actually pushes your windows OS up the stack and runs it on top of the hypervisor. This can have some performances impact for your windows OS, and tends to have issues with normal PC functions like hibernation and changing drivers, etc. That being said, if the laptop is going to be dedicated for virtualisation, then sure, i'd recommend Hyper-V, but if you want to use the laptop as a PC - then a type-2 hypervisor would be better suited.

Comment: This isn't exactly true. Performance impacts are minimal and I've had Hyper-V on my Win 8.1 laptop since they day it went RTM without issue. The host OS becomes the parent partition. This is different than being a guest OS.

Comment: @MDMarra Hmm, thanks for the input. Maybe I will do some more research on this topic. Cheers.

Comment: I tried pausing the guest before hibernating the host but still, when the guest is resumed it has lost the internet connection

Answer (score 0):

I have the same problem. It is definitely a bug in Hyper-V (or on the virtual network switch).

It is a lot easier and much faster to simply remove the connection sharing and share it again with the virtual switch.